# Permutations of columns in a matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, iteration

I had a quick question! I have a matrix that has say 8 columns and about 20 rows. Each index of the matrix is filled with some letter. I was wondering if there's an efficient way to produce a permutation (columns) of the matrix? I'm working on a Column Transposition Cipher, and I wanted to essentially test out every column permutation (swapping entire columns) so I can solve the cipher.

Is there an efficient way of doing this using itertools in python or any other technique I'm unaware of? Your help is greatly appreciated!

I first initialize the array doing this:

```
LMATRIX = [['' for x in xrange(8)] for x in xrange(53)]
```

Then later on fill it with letters...

E.g
Before Permutation:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
B C R H L M N O
J F K A B C D R
```

After ONE iteration of the permutation:

```
**1 0** 2 3 4 5 6 7 
**C B** R H L M N O
**F J** K A B C D R
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Depending on what data structure you use to represent the matrix using [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) seems the way to go

Comment: Yeah but how do I go about swapping columns using the newly created column permutation without using for loops? >_> Is there not a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played much with this solution but it seems to work for simple cases. The matrix is smaller for readability purpose. The idea is that `itertools.permutations` will produce the *same permutations* for each row you'll then need to `zip` them together to rebuild each permuted matrix. You'll need to generalize this code below for bigger matrixes. All read the `itertools.permutations` carefully to make sure the permutations are the "same" for all potential input

```
In [1]: import string                                                                        

In [2]: import random                                                                        

In [3]: LMATRIX = [[random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for y in xrange(3)] for x in xrange(2)]

In [4]: def print_mat(m):
   ...:     for row in m:
   ...:         print row
   ...:
```

The original matrix is:

```
In [5]: print_mat(LMATRIX)
['V', 'E', 'E']
['G', 'X', 'T']


In [6]: from itertools import permutations

In [7]: for perm in zip(permutations(LMATRIX[0]), permutations(LMATRIX[1])):
   ...:     print_mat(perm)
   ...:     print "\n"
   ...:     
('V', 'E', 'E')
('G', 'X', 'T')

('V', 'E', 'E')
('G', 'T', 'X')

('E', 'V', 'E')
('X', 'G', 'T')

('E', 'E', 'V')
('X', 'T', 'G')

('E', 'V', 'E')
('T', 'G', 'X')

('E', 'E', 'V')
('T', 'X', 'G')
```

Comment: This is perfect! Now how would I go about doing this for a 8 x 52 matrix? (8 columns by 52 rows) haha...

Comment: I'm thinking that you'll probably need [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to handle bigger matrixes. Also it could be a good idea to take a look at  [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) for your matrix operations

Comment: Ah okay I'll try to figure it out. Thanks for your help.